# Using requests.json() returns a list, not JSON

Tags: python, json, github, python-requests

I'm trying to get the `tag_name` from a GitHub pull request but I always get a list and not a JSON, no matter what I do. I want to be able to separate `tag_name` and use it for other things.

Code:

```
json_file = requests.get(url = "https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPONAME/releases", auth=("USERNAME","TOKEN")).json()
```

It always returns a list.

```
"[{\"url\":\"https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPONAME/releases/42178803\",\"assets_url\":\"https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPONAME/releases/42178803/assets\",\"upload_url\":\"https://uploads.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPONAME/releases/42178803/assets{?name,label}\",\"html_url\":\"https://github.com/USERNAME/REPONAME/releases/tag/v1.0-pre\",\"id\":42178803,\"author\":{\"login\":\"USERNAME\",\"id\":72929861,\"node_id\":\"MDQ6VXNlcjcyOTI5ODYx\",\"avatar_url\":\"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/72929861?v=4\",\"gravatar_id\":\"\",\"url\":\"https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME\",\"html_url\":\"https://github.com/USERNAME\",\"followers_url\":\"https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME/followers\",\"following_url\":\"https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME/following{/other_
[{'url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPONAME/releases/42178803', 'assets_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPONAME/releases/42178803/assets', 'upload_url': 'https://uploads.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPONAME/releases/42178803/assets{?name,label}', 'html_url': 'https://github.com/USERNAME/REPONAME/releases/tag/v1.0-pre', 'id': 42178803, 'author': {'login': 'USERNAME', 'id': 72929861, 'node_id': 'MDQ6VXNlcjcyOTI5ODYx', 'avatar_url': 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/72929861?v=4', 'gravatar_id': '', 'url': 'https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME', 'html_url': 'https://github.com/USERNAME', 'followers_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME/followers', 'following_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME/following{/other_user}', 'gists_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME/gists{/gist_id}', 'starred_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME/starred{/owner}{/repo}', 'subscriptions_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME/subscriptions', 'organizations_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME/orgs', 'repos_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME/repos', 'events_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME/events{/privacy}', 'received_events_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME/received_events', 'type': 'User', 'site_admin': False}, 'node_id': 'MDc6UmVsZWFzZTQyMTc4ODAz', 'tag_name': 'v1.0-pre', 'target_commitish': 'main', 'name': 'Prerelease', 'draft': False, 'prerelease': True, 'created_at': '2021-04-29T05:11:16Z', 'published_at': '2021-04-29T05:17:06Z', 'assets': [], 'tarball_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPONAME/tarball/v1.0-pre', 'zipball_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/USERNAME/REPONAME/zipball/v1.0-pre', 'body': 'Prerelease for a little test'}]
```

(just did a print(json_file.json()), here is the result)

I have no idea what is happening, Please help.

Comment: It's correct. Json is a string with a combination of lists, dicts, strings and numbers. When you do `Response.json()`, you convert it to python objects. Usually json has a dict as top level thing (is that what you mean by that it should return a json?), but here it's a list - so you get a list when converting.

Comment: @h4z3 Yup. the JSON that I am used to is most likely a dict, a type that I can use  `print(json_file["tag_name"])` on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *should* return a list. After all, what you get from the `releases` endpoint, e.g. https://api.github.com/repos/python-babel/babel/releases, is a list.

```
import requests
resp = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/python-babel/babel/releases")
resp.raise_for_status()
releases_list = resp.json()
for release in releases_list:
    print(release["tag_name"])
```

prints out

```
v2.9.1
v2.9.0
v2.8.1
v2.8.0
v2.7.0
v2.6.0
v2.5.3
v2.5.2
v2.5.1
v2.5.0
v2.4.0
2.3.4
2.3.2
2.3.1
2.2.0
2.1.1
```

Comment: Then is there a way to get only the tag name? I wanted to get JSON for the print(json_file["tag_name"])

Comment: If you want the tag name for the latest release, `print(releases_list[0]["tag_name"])`

Comment: The JSON from the GitHub API is decoded into a Python list of dicts – index 0 gets the first release (which is the latest since the API returns latest-first), and then you just access the dict as per usual.